# wxGetStockLabel(): invalid stock item ID

Tags: wxpython

How to avoid this error:

```
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at /Users/robind/projects/bb2/dist-osx-py37/build/ext/wxWidgets/src/common/stockitem.cpp(213) in wxGetStockLabel(): invalid stock item ID
```

while calling:

```
ID_SAVE =wx.NewId()
wx.MenuItem(self, ID_SAVE , label)
```

I tried with `wx.ID_ANY` and I got also the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stock` item id's can be found here:
[wxpython stock items](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/stock_items.html)

It refers to things like wx.ID_FILE, wx.ID_FIND, wx.ID_FIRST, wx.ID_FLOPPY, wx.ID_FORWARD etc a standard id providing an icon for inclusion in a menu.

The items use other than assignment to a "stock" image, is a unique id to enable you to `Bind` to, for activating a routine when the menu item is selected.

Here is some sample code, with 2 methods of inserting a menuitem, both with an image, into a menu called `self.filem`

```
self.filem = wx.Menu()
self.filem.Append(wx.ID_FILE, 'Open &Location', 'Open Location')
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnLocation, id=wx.ID_FILE)

q1 = wx.MenuItem(self.filem, wx.NewIdRef(), "Add to Job Q&ueue")
q1.SetBitmap(fs_images.getqueueaddBitmap())
self.filem.Append(q1)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnJobOpen, id=q1.GetId())
```